# htaccess, get параметры

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^id(\d+)$ profile?id=$1 [L]
```

Этот реврайт дает мне: “/id1” заместо: “profile?id=1”.

А не подскажите теперь как мне сделать реврайт из: “/profile?id=1&history=1” в “/id1/history”?

Comment: А зацикливания не боитесь? Сначала туда редиректите, потом обратно.

Comment: Дайте код пожалуйста, я в htaccess вообще 0, выстраиваю его при помощи гугла)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте эту строчку:

```
RewriteRule ^id(\d+)\/history$ profile?id=$1&history=1 [L]
```

Comment: 404 Page  Not found

Comment: @sabotage911 сорри, ошибся с одним слэшом. написал исправленную версию, попробуйте так.